# Allocate margin for sidenotes only if there is one

Tags: geometry, marginnote

Is is it possible to have a setup such that the margin allocated for page layout will be used only if there is a margin note on a given page, otherwise the page flow will be normal, as if there is no such margin?

[image]

Comment: What if a side figure overflows to the next section? I mean, what rules you want to use to decide where the text should be narrow and where it should be wide? Anyway, this one might call for `wrapfig` package.

Comment: the short answer is no it is not possible, tex linebreaking happens before page breaking and so you can only change the effective text width at forced breaks such as `\clearpage` the linebreaking after an automatic page break has to be the same before or after the break.

Comment: @David Is it possible to have a setup that will change the margins for a "section" of a book?